# What decides the cipher list in OpenSSL

Tags: windows, macos, encryption, openssl

When I integrate OpenSSL into my project. And I know I can use openssl ciphers command to list all the cipher list and manually specify cipher list by passing the results from previous command into SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list function.

My first question is: how can I set this cipher list programmatically with a security level filter?

Another question is what facts can influence this cipher list? Will the same version of openSSL on different OS result in the same cipher list?

Comment: You need to be much more specific in your question, please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).